# How to catch uncaught runtime exceptions in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf

Recently, I spent 8 hours debugging my JSF code. The cause of the failure was a `ClassNotFoundException`, which didn't appear neither in the console output, nor in the log file.

In normal Java application I can use `Thread.setDefaultUnhandledExceptionHandler(...)` to log uncaught exceptions. But it didn't help in my JSF application.

How can I implement logging (ideally - to log file and console, minimally - to standard error) of uncaught runtime exceptions in a JSF application?

**Update:**

- JSF application project `app` referenced (contained a Maven dependency on) project `logic` and `commons` version 1.
- `commons` project version 2 contained a class `X`.
- `commons` project version 1 didn't contain class `X`.
- `logic` project required and contained a dependency on `commons` version 2.
- `ClassNotFoundException` occurred on class `X`.

The problem could be reproduced by this test case:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    try {
        EntryPageController objectUnderTest = new EntryPageController();
        objectUnderTest.init();
        objectUnderTest.resetButtonAction();
        objectUnderTest.simulateYearButtonAction();
    } catch (Throwable exception) {
        LOGGER.error("", exception);
        Assert.fail(exception.getMessage());
    }
}
```

where `EntryPageController` is a JSF `ManagedBean`.

Comment: Where exactly is this exception been thrown? Can you please show an SSCCE which demonstrates the problem of the exception being swallowed? JSF has indeed several places where it swallows exceptions (mostly just event listener methods), but they are definitely logged. Are you sure that your j.u.l.Logger settings are proper?

Comment: See title of [1st Google hit](http://google.com/search?q=sscce) and last point of "Information to provide" section in [JSF tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info).

Comment: @BalusC See my update with a more detailed description of the problem.

Comment: I fail to see how exactly this is a JSF problem.

Comment: In a console or GUI Java application I can catch and log such exceptions using `Thread.setDefaultUnhandledExceptionHandler(...)`. I tried to do the same in JSF, but it didn't work (the exception didn't appear anywhere).

Comment: It seems more like a problem in the container, not in JSF.

Comment: I assume that there is a standard method for setting up a mechanism, which displays uncaught runtime exceptions in JSF. If this assumption is correct, please tell me - what is the proper way to log uncaught runtime exceptions in JSF?